# When will answerswarm winners be announced?

Tags: discussion, contests, answer-swarm

Just curious as to when the winners are announced/prizes sent. It wasn't anywhere in the Answerswarm site (unless I'm really THAT blind).

Comment: I've been in contact with Aarthi, and the word is: soon.

Comment: Soon or Blizzard Soon?

Comment: soon as in valve time https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Valve_Time

Comment: http://www.wowwiki.com/Soon#Blizzard.27s_Official_Definition_of_Soon